# Cannot Declare Field to be of Abstract Type from nested templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, abstract-class

I am trying to make an abstract playlist, with the qualifier that I use a template setInterface.h, and make Set.h, Playlist.h, and Song.h .

Everything works fine until I add Playlist.h, when I get "error: cannot declare field 'PlayList::playlist_' to be of abstract type 'Set'".

Here is the code:

SetInterface.h

```
    #ifndef SET_INTERFACE_H_

    #define SET_INTERFACE_H_

    #include <vector>

    template<class ItemType>

    class SetInterface{

    public:

       /** Gets the current number of entries in this set.
    */
       virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;

       /** Checks whether this set is empty.
    */
       virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

       /** Adds a new entry to this set.
    */
       virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
       /** Removes a given entry from this set,if possible.

    */
       virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;

       /** Removes all entries from this set.
    */
       virtual void clear() = 0;

       /** Tests whether this set contains a given entry.
    */
       virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

       /** Fills a vector with all entries that are in this set.
    */
       virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0; 

    }; // end SetInterface

    #endif /* SET_INTERFACE_H_ */
```

Set.h

```
#ifndef Set_H_

#define SET_H_
#include "SetInterface.h"

template <class ItemType> 
class Set: public SetInterface<ItemType>{
    public:
    Set();
        //Overriding SetInterface functions

    int getCurrentSize();

    bool isEmpty();

    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);

    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);

    void clear();

    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry);

    std::vector<ItemType> toVector();

    private:
    static const int DEFAULT_SET_SIZE = 4; // for testing purposes we will keep the set small

    ItemType items_[DEFAULT_SET_SIZE]; // array of set items

    int item_count_;                  // current count of set items

    int max_items_;    // max capacity of the set

    // post: Either returns the index of target in the array items_
    // or -1 if the array does not contain the target
    int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;
};

#endif /*SET_H_*/
```

and finally Playlist.h

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H_
#define PLAYLIST_H_
class PlayList: public Set<Song>{//inherits Set with Song replacing ItemType
    public:
    PlayList();
    PlayList(const Song& a_song);

    private:
    Set<Song> playlist_;//error: cannot declare field 'PlayList::playlist_' to be of abstract type 'Set<Song>'
};

#endif /*PLAYLIST_H_*/
```

Set.h and PlayList.h are defined through their respective cpp files, but it seems to be an issue with how I implemented the playList class. From what I understand the Set template class defines all the virtual functions in the SetInterface class(via the Set.cpp file), without issue, but I cannot declare a Set object still? I am at a loss.

Any help as always is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is why `override` keyword was introduced with C++11. You didn't override your methods because `const` specified is missed.

Add in derived class:

```
std::vector<ItemType> toVector() override;
```

and see error. Then change to :

```
std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const override;
```

and see again. Add `const` to all methods where it is necesarry. If you have in base class const - qualified member you need to provide `const` in derived class too.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue marvelously.